# Distinct Count in fastreport

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Does anyone know how to make a distinct count in fastreport? 
Example
I have the report:

```
 Name   sex
 João    m
 João    m
 Maria   f
```

In the normal count, the result would be 3, but I want one that takes only the number of rows that do not repeat the field name .
In this case, the result would be 2. 
Can anyone help me? That's just an example. 
I can not do a group by in SQL because I have several fields.

Comment: You have SQL Server?

Comment: No... Firebird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not skilled in using `FastReport` but I've found [this page](https://www.fast-report.com/en/forum/index.php?showtopic=6394) on the `FastReport`'s official forum.

I think you can change the example by adapting it to your scenario (Note that the syntax could require some adjustments).

**Bands:**

```
GroupHeader1 <Sex> 
MasterData1 [Name, Sex, ...] 
GroupFooter1 [GetDistinctCount]
```

**Script (Only working with dataset sorted by the field to count):**

```
var 
  LastValue : string;
  DistinctCount : integer;

//create this event by double-clicking the event from the Object Inspector
procedure OnGroupHeader1.OnBeforePrint;
begin
  if LastValue <> (<Datasetname."Sex">) then
    Inc(DinstinctCount);

  LastValue := <Datasetname."Sex">
end;

function GetDistinctCount: string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(DistinctCount);
end;
```

The base idea is that the `DistinctCount` variable is incremented each time the field value changes.

**Script (Should works also with unsorted dataset):**

```
var 
  FoundValues : array of string;


(* !!IMPORTANT!!
You need to initialize FoundValues array before to start counting: *)
SetLength(FoundValues, 0);


function IndexOf(AArray : array of string; const AValue : string) : integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  while(Result < Length(AArray)) do
  begin
    if(AArray[Result] = AValue) then
      Exit;
    Inc(Result);
  end;
  Result := -1;
end;

//create this event by double-clicking the event from the Object Inspector
procedure OnGroupHeader1.OnBeforePrint;
begin
  if(IndexOf(FoundValues, <Datasetname."Sex">) = -1) then
  begin
    SetLength(FoundValues, Length(FoundValues) + 1);
    FoundValues[Length(FoundValues) - 1] := <Datasetname."Sex">;
  end;
end;

function GetDistinctCount: string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Length(FoundValues));
end;
```

The base idea is that each different value found is added to the `FoundValues` array.

Comment: That way it worked fine ... but only if it is sorted by the item I want to cout. If it's messy, it keeps coming, coming in the wrong way ...

Ex.:

Name sex
Joao m
Joao m
Maria f

The result of count = 2 is correct

Name sex
Joao m
Maria f
Joao m

The result is 3 ... incorrect

Comment: @sounobre: I've updated the answer by adding a method which should works also with an unsorted dataset

Comment: SetLength(FoundValues, 0);
Is showing error after setlength
':' Expected

Comment: I can not initialize FoundValues

Comment: @sounobre: I'm not familiar to _FastReport_, I think you should place `SetLength(FoundValues, 0);` in an event or anything else is executed once and *before* `FoundValues` array is used. (The part from "!!!IMPORTANT!!!" to "...start counting:" must be removed, its just a warning because I think that it won't work without initializing the array)

Comment: I've tried it anyway ... if I enter a function or procedure, it returns an error:

variant or safe array index out of bounds

Comment: what means _"if I enter a function or procedure"_? did you placed `SetLength(FoundValues, 0);` in order it's executed before the other code who uses the `FoundValues` array?

Comment: Try to use TStringList in the script. Add new items to the list and then get TStringList.Count

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Firebird without `GROUP BY` as:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY (1,1), Name NVARCHAR(25) , Sex CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Sami','M'),
('Sami','M'),
('Maria','F');

SELECT DISTINCT Name , Sex FROM @T
```

You can also create a [`View`](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-create-view.html) , and then use it in your report.

If you really need to do that in `FastReport`, you have to use a `GroupHeader` and a `GroupFooter` to that.

> How ?

You have to write your script in `OnBeforePrint` event.

```
procedure OnGroupHeader1.OnBeforePrint;
```

Create this one by double-clicking in the event in the object inspector.

Comment: If you have to write a script, you don't have to use `GroupHeader`, but any control that can display values. But that seems to be overkill. I bet there is a simple way.

Comment: What would this script look like?

Comment: This option "procedure OnGroupHeader1.OnBeforePrint;" is what I was thinking .. just do not know how to act with it ...

Comment: @Victoria, a simpler option would be ideal ... kk

Comment: I think you could create an aggregate field in your dataset (with grouping level 2) over an composition index.